# Why do these answer differ when integrating the square root of $\tan x$ using complex numbers?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

The screenshot below shows a step of simplification that, intuitively, I thought made sense. Simply rewriting the one square root as a product of the sqrt(-1) times the remaining square root. Then writing the sqrt(-1) as i, and making it a coefficient.

$I = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\arctan{\left(\sqrt{-i\tan{x}}\right)} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\operatorname{arctanh}{\left(\sqrt{-i\tan{x}}\right)} $

$I = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\arctan{\left(i\sqrt{i\tan{x}}\right)} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\operatorname{arctanh}{\left(i\sqrt{i\tan{x}}\right)} $

However, upon investigating the graphs, these two answers are different.
Can anyone explain the discrepancy? Did I make an error in assumption?

Comment: Ignoring all the trigonometric clutter, your question boils-down to why $$\sqrt{-i}\neq i\sqrt{i}$$
To verify this, try writing each side in exponential form.

Comment: It is not true in general that $(a_1a_2)^b=a_1^ba_2^b$ if $a_1,a_2$ are complex numbers. The above equality though always holds for when $a_1,a_2$ are positive real numbers (the exponent can be complex with no problem). One simpler example that shows that this property fails when the $a_i$'s are not positive, is the following: $$\left((-1)(-1)\right)^{\frac12}=1^{\frac12}=1\neq -1 = i\cdot i=(-1)^{\frac12}(-1)^{\frac12}$$